# Isogeny problem for elliptic curves over the rationals

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves

Let $E$ and $E'$ be two elliptic curves over the rationals. How do we solve the $\mathbb{Q}$-isogeny problem

> Is there an isogeny $\phi: E \to E'$ defined over $\mathbb{Q}$?

- I do only know some very basic elliptic curve theory. Hence I am interested in some theoretical answers (what are the standard references here?).
- Moreover, I would like to know if there is some deterministic algorithm solving this problem (again, I would appreciate any references!) If there are, then do they compute such an isogeny?

Comment: I don't know about any kind of deterministic algorithm, but it is a fact that elliptic curves are isogenies if and only if their rational Tate modules are isomorpic (as Galois representations). Now using the modularity theorem this says that the associated modular forms are the same. This means you could compute the conductor of the elliptic curve $E$ and search the space of weight $2$ modular forms until you find which modular forms belongs to $E$ and then check whether this is also the modular form for $E'$. ....

Comment: .....In practice, this would mean you would compute points of the elliptic curves $E, E'$ over finite fields $\mathbb{F}_q$. If they are not isogenous then there is a finite field over which they have a different amount of points. If the number of points is equal for enough finite field (for example to specify a unique normalized eigenform), then they should be isogenous. (I am not a 100% sure about all of this, however).